# Branch cut of $\sqrt{x^2-1}$?

Tags: plotting, complex

I'd like to plot `expr=Sqrt[(x+I y)^2-1]` in the complex plane to see its branch cut. Real part looks like:

```
Plot3D[Re[Sqrt[(x + I y)^2 - 1]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

And imaginary part looks like:

```
Plot3D[Im[Sqrt[(x + I y)^2 - 1]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

In both plots we can see that apart from the expected branch cut along the x-axis in the interval `{-1,1}` we also get a discontinuity along the y-axis. How to get rid of the y-axis discontinuity and plot the function correctly, with only one branch cut (on the x-axis at `{-1,1}`)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is based on a mathematical misunderstanding, as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/166854). You can't do what you're asking, unless you define the function with a case distinction depending on the real part of `z`. That is, you can't choose the branch cut of the square root function once and for all, independently of `z`, to get the plot you are looking for.

The case distinction that's required is this:

```
f[z_] := Piecewise[{{-Sqrt[z^2 - 1], Re[z] >= 0}, {Sqrt[z^2 - 1], 
    True}}]

Plot3D[Re[f[x + I y]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 1}, Exclusions -> None, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: im]

```
Plot3D[Im[f[x + I y]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 1}, Exclusions -> None, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: re]

Here, I also added `Exclusions -> None` and increased the number of `PlotPoints` to get a good display.

Comment: The reason I call this a misunderstanding is: there exists no definition of the function `Sqrt` (with a branch cut in the form of a half-line from the origin in any direction) that makes `f[z]` equal to `Sqrt[z^2-1]`.

Comment: +1, but I think you have the `Re` and `Im` plots backwards.

Comment: @Jens: I think you flipped the images of the real and imaginary parts.

Comment: @Rahul, Pirx thanks for pointing that out, I swapped the figures...